# Calculate number of groups and group size with multiple criteria

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, partition

My data looks like this:

[image]

I need to calculate the last two columns (`noofgrp` and `grpsize`) No of Groups (count of Clientid) and Group Size (number of clients in each group) according to begtim and endtime. So I tried the following in the first Temp table

```
GrpSize= count(clientid) over (partition by begtime,endtime) else 0 end
```

and in the second Temp Table, I have

```
select
,GrpSize=sum(grpsize)
,NoofGrp=count(distinct grpsize)
From Temp1
```

The issue is for the date of 5/26, the `begtime` and `endtime` are not consistent. In `Grp1` (group 1) all clients starts the session at 1030 and ends at 1200 (90 minutes session) except one who starts at 11 and end at 1200 (row 8). For this client since his/her `endtime` is the same as others, I want that client to be in the first group(`Grp1`). Reverse is true for the second group (`Grp2`). All clients `begtime` is 12:30 and `endtime` is 1400 but `clientid=2` (row 9) who `begtime =1230` but `endtime = 1300`. However, since this client `begtime` is the same as the rest, I want that client to be in the second group (`grp2`) My partition over creates 4 groups rather than two. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte1 as (
select date1,id,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by date1) as rn
from #a
),cte2 as (
select top 1 date1,id,rn,cast('grp1' as varchar(10)) as grp ,i = 1
from cte1
union all
select b.date1,b.id,b.rn,cast('grp' + cast((case when a.id = 10 then i+1 else i end) as varchar(10)) as varchar(10)), (case when a.id = 10 then i+1 else i end)
from cte2 as a
inner join cte1 as b
on b.rn = a.rn + 1
)
select *,(case when id = 10 then 'grp' + cast(COUNT(grp) over (partition by grp) as varchar(10)) else '' end)
 from cte2
```

Comment: If this meets your expectations then rate and accept the answer